# Publish a ASP.NET application on Apache with Mono on Windows 7

Tags: c#, asp.net, apache, mono

I am trying to publish a ASP.NET application to Apache web server installed on Windows 7. The application has been developed in C# by Visual Studio 2013.
I also installed Mono-3.2.3 and I made the following configuration:

I have included in httpd.conf the line listed below:

**Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf**

**httpd-vhosts.conf** has the content listed below:

```
<VirtualHost *:88>
    AddHandler mono .aspx .ascx .asax .ashx .config .cs .asmx .axd .cshtml

    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot c:/ApacheVHosts

    <Location "/">
        SetHandler mono
        Require all granted
        DirectoryIndex default.aspx index.html
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

My directory tree is as shown below:

```
Local disk (c:)
    Apache24
    ApacheDoscRoot
    ApacheVHosts
        ConosoUniversity
        Test
```

When I digit on the browser the address

```
<http://localhost:88/test>
```

I got the following code of the page:

```
<%@ language="C#"%>
<%@ Import namespace="System.IO" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="mono" TagName="MonoSamplesHeader" src="~/controls   /MonoSamplesHeader.ascx" %>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to Mono XSP!</title>
<link href="favicon.ico" rel="SHORTCUT ICON" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/mono-xsp.css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
</head>
<body>
<mono:MonoSamplesHeader runat="server"/>
<p><table width=100%>
<tr valign="top">
<td>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:SiteMapDataSource runat="server" id="SamplesSiteMap"/>
    <asp:TreeView style="margin:10px" id="TreeView2" runat="server" DataSourceId="SamplesSiteMap"
      EnableClientScript="true"
      PopulateNodesFromClient="false"  
      ExpandDepth="2"/>
</form>
</td>
<td><p align="right"><img style="float:right" src="mono-powered-big.png" alt="Mono Powered"></p></td>
</tr></table>
</p>
</html>
```

If I digit

```
localhost:88/prova/index2.aspx
```

I got the following result:

```
XML Parsing Error: not well-formed  
Location http://localhost:88/test/index2.aspx
Line number1, column 2
```

It seems that Apache doesn't redirect the requested page to mono.
Am I forgetting something?
I can’t find any documentation on Internet about the use of Mono with Apache on Windows. All articles regarding this argument are for Linux environment.
Can I have some suggestion to solve my problem? Thank you.